# FOREIGN KEY and CHECK constraint failures

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create an SQLite3 table that checks any inserted values in 'gameLicense' to conform to 3 checks: that the license_id entered is 5 digits; the first 4 digits are integers from 0 to 9, and that the last digit is equal to the last number produced by the calculation (1 * digit_1 + 3 * digit_2 + 1 * digit_3 + 3 * digit_4).

I have written the code below, which seems to have no syntax errors, but when I attempt to populate the tables with valid data the check constraint fails, and a later foreign key referencing 'license_id' fails as well (due to the check failure in this table?)

```sql
CREATE TABLE GameLicense (
title TEXT,
release_year INTEGER,
platform TEXT,
license_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
CHECK (length(license_id) = 5),
CHECK (CAST(substr(license_id,1) AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 0 AND 9),
CHECK (CAST (substr(license_id, 5) AS UNSIGNED) = 
substr(CAST(substr(license_id,1) AS UNSIGNED) + 
3 * CAST(substr(license_id,2) AS UNSIGNED) + 
CAST(substr(license_id,3) AS UNSIGNED) + 
3 * CAST(substr(license_id,4) AS UNSIGNED), -1))
);

CREATE TABLE gameRental (
gamer_id INTEGER,
license_id TEXT,
date_out TEXT,
date_back TEXT,
rental_cost REAL,
FOREIGN KEY (license_id) REFERENCES GameLicense (license_id)
FOREIGN KEY (gamer_id) REFERENCES Gamer (gamer_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Results in:

```
Error: near line 18: CHECK constraint failed: GameLicense
Error: near line 43: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Please ignore the line numbers, I cut out some other table creations that were irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`substr(license_id,1)` doesn't return the first character of the license ID, it returns the substring starting at position 1 **up to the end of the string**. Use

```
SUBSTR(license_id, 1, 1)
```

instead. Similarly in the other cases.

Comment: Thanks, I had wrongly presumed the last argument within the substring format was only needed when more than one digit was being taken from the string. By the way, are the CASTS on the last check needed for every single substring in the formula? or does sqlite convert everything to an integer after the first?

Comment: It seems `+` already does the needed casts in SQLite: `SELECT SUBSTR("123", 1, 1) + SUBSTR("123", 3, 1);` returns `4`.